# Changing the axes on WPF toolkit charting graph throws an exception

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I've a WPF toolkit chart which I want to be able to both specify the axis range and change the data being shown. Either of these work fine independently, but when I put them together I get an exception thrown from the binding code because the axis minimum and maximum are briefly reversed.

Here's some code:

```
<Common:MultiSeriesChart SeriesSource="{Binding Data}" >
  <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis
            Orientation="X" Minimum="{Binding MinimumMass}" Maximum="{Binding MaximumMass}"/>
    <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis
            Orientation="Y" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
  </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
</Common:MultiSeriesChart>
```

And the code in the ViewModel (fairly standard MVVM stuff):

```
    private double maximumMass;
    public double MaximumMass
    {
        get { return maximumMass; }
        set
        {
            if (maximumMass != value)
            {
                maximumMass = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MaximumMass);
            }
        }
    }

    private double minimumMass;
    public double MinimumMass
    {
        get { return minimumMass; }
        set
        {
            if (minimumMass != value)
            {
                minimumMass = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MinimumMass);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I change the data being drawn I need to update the `MinimumMass` and `MaximumMass` for the X axis. First I update the `MinimumMass` to the new value, then the `MaximumMass`. This is fine unless the new `MinimumMass` value is bigger than the old `MaximumMass`, at which point the binding code in the graph throws an InvalidOperationException: `The minimum value must be smaller than or equal to the maximum value.`

I could update them in the opposite order, but then I'd get the same problem in reverse. Does anyone know the correct way to deal with this without a horrible kludge to ensure the maximum is temporarily too big to be beaten (i.e. set maximum to `double.MaxValue`, then set minimum to new minimum, then maximum to new maximum)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I just checked the order before assigning the new value:

```
if (newMin > MaximumMass)
{
    MaximumMass = newMax;
    MinimumMass = newMin;
}
else
{
    MinimumMass = newMin;
    MaximumMass = newMax;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try and catch

```
try
{
   min = a;
   max = b;
}
catch(exception)
{
   // reassign values here for min, max
   min = a;
   max = b;
}
```

Good Luck!